# Is there a primary Hadith book with chains compiled after the time of Imam Bayhaqi?

Tags: hadith, uloom-al-hadith

As far as I know The Sunan al Kubra of Imam Bayhaqi is the last primary hadith book. And by primary I mean the author wrote down what was directly narrated to him, not merely rearranged some existing hadiths into a new collection.

I could not find any Hadith books compiled later than the books of Bayhaqi, which were written about 430 years after the death of the prophet, according to Wikipedia.

Are there any primary Hadith collections,(with chains) collected after Bayhaqi?